# Getting the current chat room ID in Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sequelize.js

I need `roomId` (an `auto_increment` primary key) to locate a specific room to update chat info. My way of doing it right now is dumb.

In `createRoom.js`, I use `roomName` from a form that a user has entered to create a room model and find its `roomId`, then make `roomId` a param of a URL:

```
var Room = require('../models/database').Room

exports.create = function (req, res) {


Room
    .create({
        room_name: req.body.roomName
    })
    .complete(function () {

        Room
            .find({where: {room_name: req.body.roomName}})
            .success(function (room) {


                res.redirect('rooms/videochat/' + req.body.roomName + '/' + room.room_id);


        })

    })

};
```

in `routes.js`, I grab `roomId` with `req.params.roomId` and pass it to a view file jade so it can be displayed on a video chat page:

```
app.get('/rooms/videochat/:roomName/:roomId', function (req, res) {
    res.render('videochat.jade', {roomName: req.params.roomName, roomId: req.params.roomId});
});
```

In the client side JavaScript, I use

```
var roomId = $('#roomId span').text();
```

to get the `roomId`, then use socket.emit to pass it back to server side:

```
socket.emit('updateStartTime', roomId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following when a user disconnects

```
socket.emit('disconnect', roomId);
```

I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: it doesnt work. right now disconnect only happens when users click close window button.